# Google App Script - How to create rows according to a pattern

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am collecting data for a research project and the data is given on a per case basis. As such I am tasked with merging the data into relevant columns. I have streamlined a majority of the process however the time consuming part currently is checking for that each category is present in each case and if not adding that category as a new row. For example:

| Category | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Age | 23 |
| Sex | M |
| Drug Allergies | Nil |
| History | text |

These categories follow a specific order. That is the left column for example will always follow the order of Age, Sex, Drug Allergies, History over and over again. Every case has an age, however some are missing one of the others. Sometimes they are missing the History thus making the pattern Age, Sex, Drug Allergies, Age.

I am looking to create a script to iterate over the category column to make sure it follows the pattern, adding rows as it goes along when the pattern is broken. I have ran into trouble with iterating and adding rows and am unsure if this is possible. Ideally I would also like to fill the corresponding data row with "Nil". Again, not sure if this is possible. Sorry for long text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't your data better be suited to columns rather than rows?  `[[Age,Sex,Drug Allergies,History],[23,M,Nil,Text]]` Your data will get very long.

Comment: @TheWizEd said `Your data will get very long.` This is 100% correct, and worse that this, it will be a nightmare to analyse and report on your data if it is isn't column-oriented.  You said `As such I am tasked with merging the data into relevant columns.` Is your data already in the spreadsheet? Is it already entered in a row-wise format? Would you like help to re-organise the data in a column-wise format?

Comment: @Tedinoz So I have written a script to merge all the data into columns however the problem im having is that because some of the data is missing categories when I merge the data into columns it skips to the next row thus making the data incorrect. Sorry if thats confusing. Unfortunately the data is provided in list format for each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of converting rows as you have shown to column wise data.  The data on the left is convert to rows shown on right

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function test(value) {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    data.shift(); // remove the header row
    let results = [["Age","Sex","Drug Allergies","History"]];
    let row = ["Nil","Nil","Nil","Nil"];
    data.forEach( values => {
        let index = results[0].indexOf(values[0]);  // find the column
        if( index < 0 ) throw "Column ["+values[0]+" ] not found";
        if( row[index] !== "Nil" ) {  // start a new row
          results.push(row);
          row = ["Nil","Nil","Nil","Nil"];
        }
        row[index] = values[1];
      }
    );
    results.push(row);  // push the last row
    sheet.getRange(1,5,results.length,4).setValues(results);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**References**

- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)
- [Array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: thank you so so much! This is wonderful and is a huge help. Thank you thank you